# What is the purpose of SWIGTYPE_p_void in pjsip and how can i use to pass data into function parameter?

Tags: java, android, swig, pjsip

I am using PJSIP for creating an VOIP based application with Instant message functionality. Now, I want add delivery report in it for each message. And by going through [PJSIP Document](http://www.pjsip.org/docs/book-latest/html/presence.html#instant-messaging-im) and it is written their that I can use `Account.onInstantMessageStatus()` for checking the outgoing message status. But the problem is that how can I specify that the following message status is of following sent message. So I dig deeper and found [this](http://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/structpj_1_1SendInstantMessageParam.htm#a1b160ecf572a5e1a452cb08c31005c55) from which I can send unique ID of the message and can get back it on `Account.onInstantMessageStatus()`.
Now, the Actual problem is that in JAVA API for PJSIP `SendInstantMessageParam.setUserData()` takes SWIGTYPE_p_void as parameter. My question is to how to use this datatype in java to send user data over SIP messsage?
Thankyou

Comment: You can get user data as SWIGTYPE_p_void by calling getUserData()

Comment: but how can I set user data using SWIGTYPE_p_void on the first place?

Comment: I think you get user data back when the IM callback is called.

Comment: again.. how can I set it on the first place?

Comment: You can retrieve user data from getUserData() or from IM callback status, then pass it as argument in setUserData (), or do I miss something?

Comment: yes because getUserData is only accessible from Account callback. setUserData() is when you are setting it in SendInstantMessageParam .. they are in different classes

Answer (score 0):

@awaistoor Just happened across this while I was looking for an answer to the same problem.
It's a pity nobody understood your question!

A work around I have used;
First, org.pjsip.pjsua2.SWIGTYPE_p_void in your project must be changed so that the Class methods are public.

Then I have a couple of helper methods to get/set UserData (this is on an IM not a Call);

```
// Get the Userdata from an IM OnInstantMessageStatusParam
public static long getIMUserData(OnInstantMessageStatusParam prm) {
    SWIGTYPE_p_void p = prm.getUserData();
    return SWIGTYPE_p_void.getCPtr(p);
} // getIMUserData

// Set the Userdata in a SendInstantMessageParam
public static void setIMUserData(SendInstantMessageParam prm, long value) {
    prm.setUserData(new SWIGTYPE_p_void(value, false));
} // getIMUserData
```